# MapReduce word count which finds a specific word in the data set

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I'm working on a simple map reduce program using the Kaggle data set 
https://www.kaggle.com/datasnaek/youtube-new

The dataset contains 40950 records of videos with 16 variables such as video_id , trending_date , title, channel_title, category_id, publish_time, tags, views, likes, dislikes, comment_count, description etc.

The purpose of my MapReduce program is to find all videos which contain "iPhoneX" in its description and has atleast 10,000likes. The final output should only contain (title, video count)

Driver class 
package solution;

```
public class Driver extends Configured implements Tool{
    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception{
        if(args.length != 2){
        System.out.printf("Usage: Driver <input dir> <output dir> \n");
        return -1;
        }
        Job job = new Job(getConf());
        job.setJarByClass(Driver.class);
        job.setJobName("iPhoneX");

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.setMapperClass(Mapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reducer.class);

        //Specify Combiner as the combiner class

        job.setCombinerClass(Reducer.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        if(job.getCombinerClass() == null){
            throw new Exception("Combiner not set");
        }

        boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);
        return success ? 0 : 1; 

    }
    /* The main method calls the ToolRunner.run method,
     * which calls the options parser that interprets Hadoop terminal
     * options and puts them into a config object
     * */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new Driver(),args);
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }
}
```

Reducer class

```
package solution;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

public class Reducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>{

    @Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
    throws IOException, InterruptedException{

        int video_count = 0;
        for(IntWritable value : values){
            video_count += value.get();
        }
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(video_count));
    }
}
```

Mapper class

```
public class Mapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    private Text description = new Text();
    private IntWritable likes = new IntWritable();
    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)

    throws IOException, InterruptedException{

        String line = value.toString();
        String str[] = line.split("\t");

        if(str.length > 3){
            description.set(str[8]);
        }

// Testing how many times the iPhoneX word is located in the data set       
//      StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(line);
//      
//      while(itr.hasMoreTokens()){
//          String token = itr.nextToken();
//          if(token.contains("iPhoneX")){
//              word.set("iPhoneX Count");
//              context.write(word, new IntWritable(1));
//          }
//      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, but you're going to need to uncomment the part of the mapper that outputs any data, however, your mapper key should just be "iPhone" and you probably want to tokenize the description, not the entire line

You'll also want to extract the number of likes and filter out only those that match the listed condition of the problem set

By the way, you need at least 9 elements to get that position, not just three, so change the condition here

```
if(str.length >= 9){
    description.set(str[8]);

    likes = Integer.parseInt(str[...]);
    if (likes >= 10000) {
        // TODO: find when description string contains iPhoneX 
        context.write("IPhoneX", count);
    } 
} else {
    return; // skip line 
}
```

Alternatively, rather than pre-aggregating in the mapper, you could just write out (token, 1) for every token that is "iPhoneX", then let the combiner and reducer do the summation for you

Comment: FWIW, less code is required if using Spark rather than MapReduce. Might run faster as well

Comment: Alright Thank you... will try to do it now. Btw What do you mean by "tokenize the description, not the entire line"

Comment: `new StringTokenizer(line)` will include number of likes, tags, the video title, etc. that shouldn't be counted